# how do I strip html with jQuery inside a function

Tags: jquery

I want to write a function that uses the jquery function text() to replace html inside a string

tried this:

```
function formatData(inputstring) {

   // strip HTML
   var output = $(inputstring).text();

   // ... do some more stuff with output

   return output ;
}
```

and then use it like

```
alert (formatData("some <b>html</b> stuff"))
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: how do you call it ? input should be a valid jQuery selector.

Comment: input should be a string

Comment: okay so you need to pass a proper selector. eg. the id of the HTML element you want to analyze

Comment: there is no dom element. I just want to pass a string

Comment: Can you give an example of the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the string is a valid jQuery object before getting `text()` from it, I'm making a function since it's what you asked for, but it could be done inline if you don't call it many time.

```
function removeHtml(input){
    return $("<span>"+input+"</span>").text();
}

alert(removeHtml("I was a string with <h1>HTML!</h1>"));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jadJe/2/)

Comment: thanks, that worked! strange, that it worked also with a missing > at the end span ;)

Comment: @rubo77 although it worked (it was a typo) you should close it :)

Comment: I add this: `input = input.replace("<br>"," ");` so something like `some<br>words` are displayed correctly (maybe something like `<br clear="all" ... />`) too. I used it here: https://github.com/rubo77/TableCSVExport/blob/9510563234eba1595a2c6de4b0420456d79f5f2e/jquery.TableCSVExport.js#L141

Comment: this will be further optimized here: https://github.com/ZachWick/TableCSVExport/issues/7

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you get the input value from a form input/textarea field.
Try to do something like this:

```
var output = $('<div>' + input + '</div>').text();
```